# how to get all the products from internet store

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I'm interesting about getting all the products from a stores like amazon/macys, etc.

I want to implement it using Python. And I see two possible ways:

1) Use something like urllib(urllib2) to read page content + beautifulsoup(lxml) to parse page structure

2) Use scrapy for reading and preparing structured data.

I want to use as less resources as possible for it.

So here are 2 questions:

1) Which of the way to use and why?

2) Where to store information about all of the products?(in memory, sqlite, postgres/mysql)?

I was looking through stackoverflow, but didn't find something the same.

Comment: You might want to educate yourself on whether you are even allowed to do that. A lot of very popular websites will very liberally throw out IP bans on what you are trying to do.

Comment: @idjaw, thanks for your comment, but now I'm thinking about better solution. If I'll have any issues with bans, I'll try to resolve it by myself

Comment: for small problem I prefer `requests+lxml` but for something bigger `scrapy` can be better - it reads page automatically, can use threathing and proxies, can write to .csv file. You have to create function to find data in HTML.